Boss Hogg-type character with a wart on his nose
The film is set in the American South, possibly in the mid-20th Century.  I saw it on US TV in the 80s or early 90s.  One of the main characters reminded me of Boss Hogg from the Dukes of Hazzard.  He's depicted as selfish, corrupt, and racist; the audience is clearly not supposed to like him.  The camera frequently emphasizes a huge wart on the side of his nose.  The character seems oblivious to how ugly and distracting it is.
At some point, he involves a group of black men in one of his schemes.  He visits their shack to negotiate with them, but ends up getting into an argument and calls them a bunch of dirty n*****s.  The leader of the group casually pulls out a knife.  I specifically remember the pronunciation of his reply:

You picked the wrong bunch of nigras to be callin' nigras.

The camera cuts to the outside of the house, and the white man is heard screaming.  You assume he's being killed.  But then he comes running out of the house with blood streaming down his face.  The men he insulted have sliced off the annoying wart.

A Rage in Harlem from 1991, starring Forest Whitaker, Gregory Hines, Robin Givens and Danny Glover. It also stars John Seitz as a white racist named Lester with a huge mole on his nose. He double-crosses a black gang, so they proceed to tie him to a chair; after Lester calls them the N-word, the gang leader pulls out a knife and says, before proceeding to cut Lester's mole off:

Lester, baby... you gone and picked the wrong n*****s to call n*****s.

You can find the trailer here, and here's Lester and his mole:

